# Need help on try-catch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, promise, protractor

I am trying to use try-catch block in my protractor test, please see the code below:

```
try {
    element(by.id('usernameas')).sendKeys(data);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('error occured');
}
```

I am deliberately passing wrong locator to check whether it is going in catch block or not, currently it is giving me error `NoSuchElementError` on command prompt and test execution stops rather than going into catch block.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 17):

The call to element(locator).sendKeys returns a promise which is either resolved or rejected. The promise is part of the test's [control flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md).

The call to element(locator) itself does not throw an error, it is the promise which is rejected. 
If you fail to find an element you actually want your entire test to fail, since the scneario cannot be completed.

To get the error message you can use the promise callbacks, as demonstrated below.

**Important note**: if you handle the promise failure by yourself your test won't fail, so you should better rethrow it

```
try {
    element(by.id('usernameas')).sendKeys(data).then(function() {
        console.log('keys sent successfully');
    }, function(err) {
        console.error('error sending keys ' + err);
        throw err;
    });
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('error occured');
}
```

The console output is (trimmed):

```
error sending keys NoSuchElementError: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 S .....
```

Comment: I didnt know this was possible! You dont really need the "try catch" at this point, unless there is a listener or larger handler for a parent, which now makes this messy in the console. It's almost useless at this point. But seriously, the error callback just saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: I want to do the same with a retry mechanism. Say, if sendKeys gets failed, I don't want to throw the error, unless it is failed after some iterations. If it is failed in 5th iteration also, then throw the error. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @Bala try handling the rejection in your code to retry the action, and after rethrow the error if it still happens after 5 times

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently and noticed that you DONT need the try/catch block. In Protractor, you can achieve the try/catch like following:

```
try {   <---------------------------- Traditional TRY/CATCH method
  loadWebApp();
  login();
  openUserPreferences();
  changePassword();
 } catch (err) {
  console.error(
      "An error was thrown! " + err);
 }

 loadWebApp().
    then(login).
    then(openUserPreferences).
    then(changePassword).
    then(null, function(err) {  <----------------- PROTRACTOR equivalent of try/catch
      console.error(
          "An error was thrown! " + err);
    });
```

Here's the source where I got this info from: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises 
under `Value Propagation and Chaining`

So again, you don't need to explicitly add a try/catch. 

In short, the reason this method works is because `a promise can either be RESOLVED or REJECTED and in case of a rejected or failed promise, this line [ then(null, function(err) { ... } ] will act as the CATCH block.` 
 
Also notice that the then(null, function(err))( is NOT taking any callback but only an errBack; so basically, this is saying we don't care about whether the promise gets resolved, we only care about whether it fails and thus the NULL for callback and the function(error) for the errBack. 
No need to wrap this in a try/catch then throw the error as suggested above by the accepted answer (@Eitan Peer). 
 Hope this helps someone out there struggling with Protractor as I did.