# Click element until another element is displayed using isDisplayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

I want to click the back button until I get to a specific page in my app (where my `expectedElement` lives). This doesn't seem to be working...

It fails because it can't find the expected element.

```
function navigateBack() {
    var backButton = $('div.back');
    var expectedElement = $('span.some-specific-class');

    backButton.click().then(function () {
        if (expectedElement.isDisplayed()) {
            expectedElement.click();
        } else {
            navigateBack();
        }
    });
}
```

I made a slight modification to use a promise on `isDisplayed()`. Protractor will throw an error when calling `isDisplayed()` on a missing element...

```
var expectedElement = $('span.some-specific-class');

expectedElement.isDisplayed().then(function(isDisplayed) {
    if(isDisplayed)
        console.log('isDisplayed');
});
```

So, unless this is invalid syntax, how do you check if an element is present or displayed if protractor will throw an error calling `isPresent()` / `isDisplayed()` ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handle the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885803/771848) thrown by `isDisplayed()`:

```
function navigateBack() {
    var backButton = $('div.back');
    var expectedElement = $('span.some-specific-class');

    backButton.click().then(function () {
        expectedElement.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
            if (isDisplayed) {
                expectedElement.click();
            } else {
                navigateBack();
            }
        }, function (err) {

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

does something like this work for you?

```
function navigateBack() {
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var isVisible = EC.visibilityOf(expectedElement);
var backButton = $('div.back');
var expectedElement = $('span.some-specific-class');

backButton.click().then(function () {
    browser.wait(isVisible, 5000, "failed to wait for element").then(function(result) {
        if(result){
            expectedElement.click();
        } else {
            navigateBack();
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: I tried but I don't believe `browser.wait` will be of use in my case? I don't really need to wait on the page for the element to show up. I'm navigating between pages and I think protractor takes care of that on it's own

Comment: yeah I guess the reason I've been having to use waits a lot is b/c the app I'm testing isn't an angular app so I've had to make use of the expected conditions.