# Functions crashes after first successful iteration (element is not attached to the page document)

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Would like to ask what is wrong with the functions bellow, the first iteration works without any problem but, after the grid is refreshed, when protractor tries to move to the next cell, it gives me this error message:

Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

The idea of this is to read the 5th column (or 4th if you consider stating from 0), check each row that contains the value "true", if contains true then do the operation of editing the row, clicking in a checkbox and saving (everything is performed at the line)
Each element has a unique ID related to status code so that why I am "not using rows" in the function (only to get the text from the line and then pass as string to complete the ID of the element)

**Every time that the value is changed and saved, the table gets a refresh

```
    function resetGoodItemStatus(siteToResetValues){
      var cellsConform = element.all(by.css('#datatableDir tr td:nth-of-type(5)'));
      var conformCounter = 0;
      selectValueDropDown(siteToResetValues)
        cellsConform.each((eachCell) => {
            eachCell.getText().then((cellText) => {
                switch (cellText)
                {
                    case 'true':
                        element(by.id(conformCounter+'-1')).getText().then(function(value){
                            element(by.id('btnEdit-US.'+value)).click();
                            element(by.xpath("//*[@editable-checkbox=\"scopeValue.getConformMapping(scopeValue.getDataRow("+'\'US.'+value+"\')).conform\"]/../span/span/input")).click();
                            element(by.id('btnSubmit-US.'+value)).click();
                        })
                    default:
                        browser.sleep(100)
                }
                conformCounter += 1
                });

        });
      }
```

HTML before editing the line:

```
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
 <td id="0-0" class="ng-scope">
<form editable-form="" name="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM']" onaftersave="scopeValue.saveData('US.DAM',0)" ng-show="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline ng-pristine ng-valid ng-hide" style="">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-trans kni kni-check-circle text-info" id="btnSubmit-US.DAM" ng-disabled="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$waiting" ng-click="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$submit()">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link kni kni-x-circle-slim" ng-disabled="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$waiting" id="btnCancel-US.DAM" ng-click="scopeValue.cancelData('US.DAM',0)">
    </button>
</form>
<div class="buttons" ng-show="!scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$visible">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-trans kni kni-edit-circle text-info" ng-click="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM'].$show()" id="btnEdit-US.DAM">
    </button>
</div></td>
<td id="0-1" class="ng-scope sorting_1">DAM</td>
<td id="0-2" class="ng-scope">US.DAM</td>
<td id="0-3" class="ng-scope">Generic Damaged Code</td>
<td id="0-4" class="ng-scope">
<span editable-checkbox="scopeValue.getConformMapping(scopeValue.getDataRow('US.DAM')).conform" e-name="conform" e-form="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM']" e-required="" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable">false</span>
</td></tr>
```

HTML after clicking at the Edit button:

```
<td id="0-4" class="ng-scope">
<span editable-checkbox="scopeValue.getConformMapping(scopeValue.getDataRow('US.DAM')).conform" e-name="conform" e-form="scopeValue.rowforms['US.DAM']" e-required="" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable editable-hide">false</span>
<span class="editable-wrap editable-checkbox ng-scope">
    <span class="editable-controls"><input type="checkbox" name="conform" required="required" class="editable-input ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="$data" style="">
        <div class="editable-error ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="$error" ng-bind="$error" style=""></div>
    </span>
</span>
</td>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Every time you refresh the table, the DOM changes and the reference to the next cell element becomes "stale".

Comment: As said above DOM marks already found element to stale once it gets refreshed So the approach should be to again find the element in catch block once we get exception.
To use try and catch in protractor please follow stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882688/need-help-on-try-catch

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers! now I can see the error message before the end of the execution but how can I exactly find again the object? I am trying to reload the page but for some reason it is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to get text of all cells in the 5th column into text array, then iterate the text array, the array index is equivalent to the table row index.

Once cell text is equal `true`, use row index to find the table row. The rest elements can be found within the table row.

Because in each iteration, below code will find all table rows from page again, should not happen `Stale Exception`

```
function resetGoodItemStatus(siteToResetValues){
    var cellsConform = element.all(by.css('#datatableDir tr td:nth-of-type(5)'));

    selectValueDropDown(siteToResetValues);

    cellsConform.getText().then(function(conforms) {

        // conforms is a string Array, each one is the text of one cell of 5th column
        conforms.forEach(function(conform, rowIndex) {

            if(conform === 'true') {
                var row = element.all(by.css('#datatableDir tr').get(rowIndex);

                row.element(by.css('button[id^="btnEdit-US"]')).click();

                row.element(by.css('input[type="checkbox"]')).click();

                row.element(by.css('button[id^="btnSubmit-US"]')).click();

                browser.sleep(3000)
            }
        });
    });

}
```